# Access - Change fields in table automatically, if a field changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

Lets say I got a table with an id, pre- and lastname. I made them work as comboboxes in the table. Now if I change 1 field (lets say the id) with the combobox I want that all the other stuff is changed too (the pre and lastname). How to achieve that (with a macro or vba, or is it easier)?

Comment: I don't think php is helping me out in MS Access?

Comment: Look up cascading combos.

Comment: Ok, sounds great, but is there a way to do this without a formular, just in the table? They don't want a formular for this.

Comment: Not that I know of, and not in any database.

Comment: I was thinking about an after-update datamacro, but idk if this will work.

Comment: BTW comboboxes in tables are a really bad idea.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but they want it that way :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I made a sub formular. Then i managed to dropdown the fields I wanted to. Copying the same table for finding the names ids...
And then i created an event for after update:

```
Private Sub PartnerIdServiceWorker_AfterUpdate()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set dbs = CurrentDb

Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM HTB WHERE PartnerIdServiceWorker = " & PartnerIdServiceWorker)

Do While Not rst.EOF
    Me.AnredeMitarbeiter = rst!AnredeMitarbeiter
    Me.VornameMitarbeiter = rst!VornameMitarbeiter
    Me.NachnameMitarbeiter = rst!NachnameMitarbeiter
    Exit Do
    rst.MoveNext
Loop

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```

Now I'm able to change the fields in the table and the other values do also change.